# How to load a Category Page with Products using pagination and filtering? Laravel

Tags: laravel

// CategoryController

```
class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function show($slug)
    {
        $category = Category::with('products')
            ->where('slug', $slug)
            ->where('menu', 1)
            ->first();

        return view('pages.category.show', compact('category'));
    }
}
```

// Product_to_categories pivot table...

```
        Schema::create('products_to_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('category_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
            $table->bigInteger('product_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

I cannot paginate the products on the page, how would you suggest paginating with Eager Loading or passing the variables separately...

I have a pivot table Category_Product also...

I also want to filter based on brand and price?

EDIT:
// product.pphp

````
class Product extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'products_to_categories', 'product_id', 'category_id');
    }
    }
    ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse it, meaning query for products instead:

```
class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function show($slug)
    {
        $products = Product::with(['categories'])->whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($slug) {
            $query->where(['slug' => $slug]);
        })->paginate();

        return view('pages.category.show', compact('products'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Tpojka that answer provides the same results as my below solution...

Comment: I always stick with framework recommendation naming convention and this primer should work. From your question we don't know if there are two tables i.e. `Category_Product` and `products_to_categories`. Keeping it simple and sticking with Laravel's naming convention your table should be lower cased `category_product`. Also, you should have relations in models that query each other. This way pagination works naturally. Test if this work `dd(\App\Product::with(['categories'])->first());` If this doesn't work, relations between models are wrongly set I'd suspect.

Comment: thanks Yes, I know about the Laravel convention... However, the place I work prefers this table naming convention. I'll check to see if that works to see if it's correct.

Comment: it does work...
```
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'products_to_categories', 'product_id', 'category_id');
    }``` because...

Comment: You need `categories()` method/relation in `Product` model and `products()` method/relation in `Category` model. Here you showed relation between category and category. Post your models and someone will tell you if those are well set.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in two steps like this:

```
class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function show($slug)
    {
        $category = Category::where('slug', $slug)->first();
        $products = Product::where('category_id', $category->id)->paginate(20);

        return view('pages.category.show', compact('category', 'products'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, However, it does not work because it is a Pivot Table...

Answer (score 1):

This with Eager Loading

```
class CategoryController extends Controller 
{
   public function show($slug)
   {
      $category = Category::with('products')->whereHas('products' => function($query) {
                  if(request()->has('price') 
                  {
                     $query->where('price',request()->input('price');
                  }
                  if(request()->has('brand') 
                  {
                     $query->where('brand',request()->input('brand');
                  }
                  })->where('slug', $slug)->paginate(20);
      return view('pages.category.show', compact('category'));
   }   
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Tpojka that answer provides the same results as this below...

```
class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function show($slug)
    {
        $category = Category::where('slug', $slug)->first();;
        $products = $category->products()->paginate(15);

        return view('pages.category.show', compact('category', 'products'));
    }
}
```